# How to access the facets in a CGAL 3D triangulation?

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

I am using [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) to compute the 3D triangulation of a set of points:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_3<K>   CGALTriangulation;
typedef CGALTriangulation::Point            Point;

// Construction from a list of points
std::list<Point> points;
points.push_front(Point(0, 0, 0));
points.push_front(Point(2, 0, 0));
points.push_front(Point(0, 2, 0));
points.push_front(Point(2, 2, 0));
points.push_front(Point(1, 1, 1));

// Perform triangulation
CGALTriangulation T(points.begin(), points.end());
```

#### Accessing triangles (facets)

I need to create a mesh out of this in Unity, so I am using CGAL because it has a lot of algorithms for taking care of this complex problem. The issue is that it is very difficult in the API to find a way to access the different triangles (and so their vertices) that compose the triangulation **and I haven't yet found a way how to do so :(**

**Note** Please note that accessing vertices alone is not enough for me:

```
for (CGALTriangulation::Finite_vertices_iterator it = T.finite_vertices_begin(); 
    it != T.finite_vertices_end(); 
    it++) 
{
    CGALTriangulation::Triangulation_data_structure::Vertex v = *it;
    // Do something with the vertex
}
```

Because I do not get any info about which facet (triangle) each vertex belongs to. And the triangles is exactly what I need!

How can I access the triangles (facets) of the triangulation? How to get the vertices out of each facet?

Comment: If you don't explain the reason for downvoting or proposing a close, how am I supposed to fix this question?

Comment: Seems like people complained about the question not being clear. I have edited it, hopefully it is better. Please if it is not clear do not just vote for closing, process it a little bit in a comment so I can take action to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know precisely what you can to achieve. A 3D Delaunay triangulation is a decomposition of the convex hull of your points into tetrahedra. Any way, if you want to access the facets of a triangulation, you use the Finite_facets_iterator.

Something like:

```
for (CGALTriangulation::Finite_facets_iterator it = T.finite_facets_begin(); 
    it != T.finite_facets_end(); 
    it++) 
{
    std::pair<CGALTriangulation::Cell_handle, int> facet = *it;
    CGALTriangulation::Vertex_handle v1 = facet.first->vertex( (facet.second+1)%4 );
    CGALTriangulation::Vertex_handle v2 = facet.first->vertex( (facet.second+2)%4 );
    CGALTriangulation::Vertex_handle v3 = facet.first->vertex( (facet.second+3)%4 );
}
```

If you are interested in a surface mesh, you might want to look a reconstruction algorithms such as [Poisson surface reconstruction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3) or [Advancing Front Reconstruction](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction).

Comment: Thank you. I had figured out that iterator was needed, but I had absolute no idea how to get the vertices. Can you explain how you knew that the first and second items of the pair were the cell handle and the index? Why `%3`? Man the doc is terrible, I have spent days trying to understand how to get this info by browsing the doc and no clue so far...

Comment: However your comments are interesting. The reason why I am looking for triangulation is because I have this problem: I have a set of points, and I want to create a surface out of them. I don't care much about the final shape, as long as it is a convex hull I'm fine with that.

I have thought that Triangulation was the algorithm to do it, but you pointed me to those links and now I am not sure. So, can you explain please the difference between a triangulation and a surface reconstruction algorithm? Thanks

Comment: If you need for a convex shape then simply use the [convex hull](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/)

Comment: Should be `% 4`, not `% 3`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Indeed. Just did the edit. Thanks!

Comment: @sloriot What is int in std::pair<CGALTriangulation::Cell_handle, int>  ?  e.g. index of all points (that are being triangulated ),  index of all tetrahedron . Is each face shared by exactly two tetrahedrons ( and  this int is the index of the other tetrahedron)?

Comment: `Cell_handle` is a handle to a tetrahedron and the int is the index of the vertex in the tetrahedron (in `[0,3]`) opposite to the facet.